# Stop a parent form from closing

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have a winforms application and I need a good way to handle the following..

Basically, I have the main application form, and within that, I have child forms.

The user can hit 'close' on the parent form.
But within the child form, some things might be happening. For instance, I may have edited some databound fields.

I currently catch the close within the child, and correctly save any changes.

However, now I want the option to cancel the close. So the child form would prompt the user, and they could actually cancel the application from closing.

I tried e.Cancel within the child form closing event, but this isn't working- I'm assuming because the parent is still closing... Is there a way to cancel the parent form's closing process from within the child...?

Comment: actually.. while the answer below is good, I did find another way that worked for me - in case it helps anyone...
in the parent form closing event, I don't bother checking a special 'canclose' item.. I just call the child form's Close() method (I have my checks and balances within the child's Closing event..it cancels it's own close if needbe) then the next line i check the child form's IsDisposed property.  If its not disposed, then I cancel the parent's close.

Comment: `parent_FormClosing(...) {
       childform.Close();
       if (!childform.IsDisposed) e.Cancel = true;
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest subscribing for `FormClosing` event in main form and validating states for each child form and prevent form close (if required). Below code might help you and give fair idea of details.

```
private void Main_FormClosing( object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e ) 
{
    foreach(var f in childforms)
    {
        if(!f.CanClose())
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    e.Cancel = false;   
}
```

Comment: i can go this route.. thanks.. however I'd still like to know if the answer to my question is "No - there is no way. period.", or if it's just not a good thing to do, or if it's just too complex...etc

Comment: @daBich Every solution varies from case to case, in this case you guessed it correctly, it is too complex and not preferable solution .

Comment: Problem is, if you have other children forms, they may have already begun to close since they execute `FormClosing` before the parent (see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing?view=netframework-4.8&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Form.FormClosing)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue#remarks)). How do you check if you `CanClose` **before** the children execute `FormClosing`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple example for one single child form. If the user entered something in Form2's textbox he will be prompted when he tries to close form1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form2 form2;

    public Form1()
    {
        form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (form2.AskBeforeClosing)
        { 
            e.Cancel = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?","",MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
        }
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public bool AskBeforeClosing
    {
        get {
            return textBox1.Text != "";
        }
    }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

If you need to work with a variable number of children form, you have to do the following:

1. Define a base class form that exposes a bool virtual readonly property `AskBeforeClosing`
2. Derive all child forms from this base class and override the property by using the specific logic to prevent accidental closing
3. Keep all children forms in a list within form1.
4. Loop the list inside the FormClosing event handler in order to find if AT LEAST one form have AskBeforeClosing = true. If so, prompt the user

Comment: thanks.. pretty much the same as Hari's answer (beat you by like 30 seconds! ;)  ).. but I'm still wondering about the other direction and if it's even possible.. ie. canceling the parent's close from the child. is it impossible?

Comment: If you try do that you simply mix responsibilities. The child form has the responsibility to tell the parent that it has some pending operations. The parent has the responsibility to alert before closing. And if you have more children, who is going to prevent the closing?  There's not another way to do it. By the way, you should approve one of the two answers :-)