# Catch close event of child form c#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

In winform application I have a main form and other form. I want to trigger the event of `FormClosing` of the other form when I click "x" in the main form.

**@Update:**

Code:

In the Program:

```
frmMain frm = new frmMain();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

In frmMain:

```
private void btnFrm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Frm2 f2 = new Frm2();
   f2 .Show();
}
```

In Frm2:

```
private void frm2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     //something
}
```

How can I trigger the event `frm2_FormClosing` when I close `frmMain`?
I know I can trigger it when I closing `frm2`, but I want to trigger it on closing `frmMain`.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question.

Comment: Do you know how to subscribe to events? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Few days back I've answered similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30115533/stop-a-parent-form-from-closing/30115756#30115756).

Answer (score 0):

Using [observer pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern) you can make notification to subscribents (child forms) when FormClosing or any other action happend on main form. In a handler of subscribent you can raise FormClosing event of it (subscribent, childform) or do whatever you want.

1. Main form is a subject
2. Child forms subscribe to the subject (main form)
3. Main form raises notify event within an action of your choice (possibly formClosing in your case)
4. All subscribents gets notified (their "notified" event is raised)
5. Inside that "notified" event you do whatever you want, e.g. raise formClosing event of the subscribent (child form)

I believe this pattern is straight-forward and very flexible. I use it to update data in many-to-many related forms.

Comment: when I close the main form all the other forms close also. but it doesn't trigger the FrmClosing event of the child forms.

Comment: I don't think this solution works for the cases @chani Poz posted.

Comment: @ChaniPoz I would suggest you to look into [Observer pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/observer-design-pattern), I believe this would be the most appropriate solution for your problem. You can make your main form subject. Check my answer for updates.

Comment: @HariPrasad you're right, my original answer applied to the original question that has been changed.